# fill an array of type class inside another class

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I am new in c++ recently i started learning poo I want to create a class `movies` and a class.
`directors` a class `movie` should have an array of `directors` and I want to fill that array from the console. When I run the code it show me the first and second line and stop executing :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBvJ5.png)
this is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

class directors{
   string name;
   string lastname;
       public:
           directors(){
               
           }
           directors(string a,string b){
               name=a;
               lastname=b;
           }
           void createdirector(){
                   cout<<"name of director:"<<endl;
                   cin>>name;
                   cout<<"last name:"<<endl;
                   cin>>lastname;
           }
       
           
};

class movie{
   string name;
   directors* director;
   public:
       film(){
           directors* director=new directors[20];
       };

       void creatmovie(){
           cout<<"name of movie"<<endl;
           cin>>name;
           director[0].createdirector();
       }   
};

int main(){ 
movie a; 
a.creatmovie(); 

}
```

Comment: Use `std::vector`. Anyhow, please extract and provide a [mcve] and the output it produces as text. As a new user her, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Being new to C++, the first thing you should do is get yourself a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/4641116).

Comment: Your code shouldn't even compile: You've added a `film` member to `movie` that uses the syntax of a constructor, but uses a name different to the name of the containing class. Furthermore any class that dynamically allocates resources should also contain logic to free those resources, usually in a destructor, so assuming you do allocate memory for the array `movie::director`, there should be destructor doing `delete[] director;` For this to work properly you need to make sure that if the constructor completes successfully, `director` either contains a value allocated via `new[]`, or null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way wold be to use `std::vector` as shown below. The **advantage** of using a `std::vector` is that you don't have to worry about manual memory management(like using `new` and `delete` explicitly). `vector` will take care of it(memory management).  You can use the below given example as a reference.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include <vector>


class director{
   std::string name;
   std::string lastname;
       public:
           director(){
               
           }
           //use constructor initializer list
           director(std::string a,std::string b): name(a), lastname(b){
               
           }
           
           void createDirector() 
           {
                   std::cout<<"Enter name of director:"<<std::endl;
                   std::cin>>name;
                   std::cout<<"Enter last name:"<<std::endl;
                   std::cin>>lastname;
           }
           void displayDirector() const
           {
               std::cout << "Firstname: "<<name<<" Lastname: "<<lastname<<std::endl;
               
           }
       
           
};

class movie{
   std::string name;
   std::vector<director> directors; //vector of director objects
   public:
       
       //constructor that creates vector directors of size vecSize 
       movie(size_t vecSize): directors(vecSize)
       {
           std::cout << "Enter name of movie: "<<std::endl;
           std::cin >> name;
           
           //iterate through the vector and call method createDirector on each element 
           for(director &elem: directors)
           {
               elem.createDirector();
           }
       }
       
       void displayMovie()
       {
           std::cout<<"Movie's name is: "<<name<<std::endl;
           //iterate through the vector and call displayDirector on each object 
           for(const director& elem: directors)
           {
               elem.displayDirector();
           }
           
       }
};

int main(){ 
    movie a(4); //create an object of type movie. Note i have passed 4 as argument you can pass other numbers like 3,2 etc
    a.displayMovie();//display movie info

}
```

Some of the modifications that i made are:

1. Used **constructor initializer list** in class `director`
2. added a method called `displayDirector` in class `director`
3. added a method called `displayMovei` in class `movie`
4. added a data member called `directors` that is a `std::vector<director>` in class `movie`.
5. added a constructor for class `movie` that **initializes** the data member `directors`.
6. removed unnecessary method named`film` from class `movie`
7. not used `using namespace std;` which is a recommended practice

The output of the above program can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/SQ-CUdAjA).